# NGINX & PASSENGER on differnt machines configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to set up a rails environment on 2 different machines.

REQUEST ----> M1 ----> M2

M1 would only run nginx and upstream to M2
M2 would hold the Rails App and passenger.

I'm not sure if 
I need to set up nginx on M2 as well (I know this works)

or if passenger only is enough on M2. If so how would the upstream configuration on M1 look like? And how would I set the passenger parameters (production etc..) on M2

```
upstream backend {
    server M2:80;
} 

server {
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
 }
```

Thanks for your help
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to setup is called a reverse proxy.
Here is an [official doc](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/reverse_proxy.html) on howto set it up with nginx.

Comment: Thanks! Would reverse_proxy be preferred vs upstream / 2nd nginx ?

Comment: You could have nginx M1 acting like a reverse proxy.
And passenger M2 started for example like
passenger start --daemonize --port 4000
It's a simple way of doing things.